# R-Markdown pdfLatex won't work when rendering shape ="\U0001f693"

Tags: pdftex, unicode, r, rmarkdown

This is my first time using r-markdown and running into problems rendering the symbol above. Everything else works great. It also works in r in ggplot2 but won't work in r-markdown. When I include "\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}" it renders but gives a document clash. I have seen solutions for using a different engine but I don't want to mess up my formatting. Anyone know a way to render the symbol without changing engines? Anyone know what packages are classing and how to rectify it? I have included all packages below.

Thanks.

```
  -\usepackage{geometry}
  - \usepackage[english]{babel}
  - \usepackage{natbib}
  - \usepackage{url}
  - \usepackage{amsmath}
  - \usepackage{graphicx}
  - \graphicspath{{S:/Analysis/ECAC/Mike_R/}}
  - \usepackage{parskip}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage{vmargin}
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{caption,booktabs,array}
  - \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
  - \usepackage{lscape}
  - \usepackage{subcaption}
  - \newcommand{\rowgroup}[1]{\hspace{-1em}#1}
  - \setmarginsrb{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}
  - \title{}
  - \author{}                               
  - \date{\today}                                   
  - \makeatletter
  - \let\thetitle\@title
  - \let\theauthor\@author
  - \let\thedate\@date
  - \makeatother
  - \pagestyle{fancy}
  - \fancyhf{}
  - \rhead{ECAC}
  - \lhead{\thetitle}
  - \cfoot{\thepage}
  - \captionsetup{font=Large}
  - \usepackage{hyperref}
  - \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: avoid `utf8x` it does not work with current latex, You could use the standard `utf8` option but that is the default so you can delete `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`

Comment: U+1F693 is a Police Car   You would need to specify  font that had that character (probably no font for pdflatex, you could use lualatex, or use an image)

Comment: If you want to include random unicode characters you really should use luatex not pdftex. You can configure pdftex to recognise some ranges but doing emoji this way will lead to pain. If you use luatex and a big unicode font they may simply "just work"

Answer (score 3):

If you used lualatex you could use a font covering this range, but with pdftex I'd use an image.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1F693}{\includegraphics[height=1em]{police.png}}

\begin{document}

U+1F693 is POLICE CAR: 

\end{document}
```

where police.png is

[image]

Comment: Does your [licensing declaration](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3332/119) apply also to hand drawn images? (I assume that's what `police.png` is.) :-)

Comment: @WillieWong I am open to commissions if you are needing such high quality artwork